# Calculating fields if Null with Field Calculator

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I have a script that runs every seven minutes and would like to calculate only rows that are `Null`.

How should this be done?

This is my initial script which calculates all fields each time.

```
    import arcpy
    calcExpression =  "!ORIGDTDATE!+\" \"+ !ORIGDTTIME!"
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,"emergency_overdue",calcExpression,"PYTHON_9.3")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc,"emergency_overdue",calcExpression,"PYTHON_9.3")
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a feature layer with an SQL statement that selects only NULL values. Let's say the field in question is `SOMEFIELD`:

```
import arcpy

fld = "SOMEFIELD"

#create SQL
delimFld = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters (fc, fld)
sql = "{} IS NULL".format (delimFld)

#create feature layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (fc, "layer", sql)

#calc
calcExpression =  "!ORIGDTDATE!+\" \"+ !ORIGDTTIME!"
arcpy.CalculateField_management("layer", "emergency_overdue", calcExpression, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: That is so time consuming and inefficient, I should be able to use a conditional statement in the field calculator.  I would then have to append my layer back to the feature class.

Comment: @geewest Negative, the layer references the underlying feature class, so updating the layer updates the feature class.

Comment: @Hornbydd True. Edited.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's faster to use multiple Make Feature Layers then build multiple `if..elif` statements inside Calculate Field. Create a table with a few million records and you'll see large differences.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a *layer* or *table view* of your data as they are objects that understand the concept of a selection. Then you select the rows with the *select by attribute* tool where your field is `Null` then run your field calculations. As these tools honour selections only the rows that are selected will be updated.

To see an example of this as code please refer to @Emil Brundage answer above.